# Application.Exit() or Environment.Exit(1) removes the exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, exit

When I do throw exception I have added the exit, but after that the exe file is removed. is it a known problem? (in VS2010)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither `Application.Exit` nor `Environment.Exit` will remove the executable from disk.

It sounds like some other process is trying to delete the executable.  As soon as the application exits, the file will no longer be in use, and the .exe could be removed.

Depending on what you're doing, this could, potentially, be from a virus scanner.  I would check your Virus Scanner logs to see if there is an issue there.  This should be very unlikely if this is a completely managed (C# only) application - but if you're using native code that is "questionable" according to the scanner, it may be removing the executable.

Otherwise, I would check for other processes that may be trying to remove the executable.

Comment: is it possible that VS is removing that file?

Comment: @01: No - VS won't remove that file, unless you have some type of custom add-in that's doing it... by VS, by itself, will leave it in place.

Answer (score 0):

No this doesnt sound right. Do you mean the .Exe Application file is been removed from Disk? That cannot/Should not happen on Exiting. Can you send mroe details on what you are trying to do, What kind of application, etc. I tried with a simple C# Console application and it wouldnt seem to happen in VS 2010.